# Method for Time Slicing in Netcdf similar to xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a NetCDF data file containing sea ice concentration

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
ds = Dataset('file.nic', 'r')
ds.variables.keys()
>>odict_keys(['latitude', 'longitude', 'seaice_conc', 'seaice_source', 'time'])
ds.dimensions.keys()
>>odict_keys(['latitude', 'longitude', 'time'])
```

**Question**: In this dataset, time is stored as days since 2001-01-01 00:00:00. Let's say I want seaice_conc for a particular time = 1990-12-01 then how do I approach it without using xarray or writing another function to calculate the days difference.
Is it possible to do it like in xarrays, for eg;

```
import xarray as xr
ds1 = xr.open_dataset('file.nc')
seaice_data = ds1['seaice_conc'].sel(time = '1990-12-01')
```

To give further info on dataset, it looks like this:

```
ds1.seaice_conc
<xarray.DataArray 'seaice_conc' (time: 1968, latitude: 240, longitude: 
1440)>
[680140800 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
* latitude   (latitude) float32 89.875 89.625 89.375 89.125 88.875 88.625 
...
* longitude  (longitude) float32 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875 1.125 1.375 1.625 
...
* time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1850-01-15 1850-02-15 1850-03-15 ...
Attributes:
short_name: concentration
long_name: Sea_Ice_Concentration
standard_name: Sea_Ice_Concentration
units: Percent
```

*Another thing* which I'm confused is that using netcdf it says that time is stored in days since 2001:01:01 but in xarrays it shows me the exact date in yyyy-mm-dd format instead of showing the 'days since...' definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach I could find is

```
from netCDF4 import date2index
from datetime import datetime
timeindex = date2index(datetime(1990,12,1),ds.variables['time'])
seaice_data = ds.variables['seaice_conc'][timeindex,:,:]
```

Answer (score 1):

netCDF4.Dataset is indeed a kind of lower level library than xarray, if it could do everything that xarray already does, there would be no need for xarray, right.
Still, there is a useful function `num2date` in netCDF4, which can make your life easier when managing the date units. Approximately:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date
import datetime
import numpy as np

ds = Dataset('file.nic', 'r')
your_date = datetime.datetime(1990,12,1)
select_time = np.argmax(num2date(ds.variables['time'][:],ds.variables['time'].units) == your_date)
seaice_data = ds.variables['seaice_conc'][select_time,:,:]
```

I admit it is still more code than xarray.

Comment: I agree with what you said. I used a similar approach to arrive at the answer albeit with a different function

Comment: @Light_B good catch, date2index is definitely a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are trying to do in Xarray.

**For Question 1**. It looks like your dates are all on the 15th of each month. Selecting just one time point should work like this.

```
ds1['seaice_conc'].sel(time='1990-12-15')
```

Another way you can do this is to use the `method='nearest'` keyword argument.

```
ds1['seaice_conc'].sel(time='1990-12-01', method='nearest')
```

Finally, you may consider reindexing your time axis to the first of each month.

```
ds1['seaice_conc'].resample(time='MS').mean('time').sel(time='1990-12-01')
```

A bonus answer, you can select time slices with a similar approach:

```
ds1['seaice_conc'].sel(time=slice('1990-01-01', '1991-12-31')
```

The Xarray documentation includes a [section on datetime indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#datetime-indexing)

**For Question 2**. Xarray automatically decodes coordinate variables when you use `open_dataset`. You can turn this off with the `decode_times` argument but that doesn't seem like what you want to do here.

This is also discussed in the Xarray [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html#reading-encoded-data).

Comment: In first Q I asked how to do it without using Xarrays. You're indexing it with xarrays which I already showed in my Question. Thanks for the explanation on Question 2.

Comment: I suggested an edit to your original question that clarifies that you don't want an xarray solution.